zookeeper large memory size
I have a zk cluster set up , however, I ran into errors:
in zookeeper.properties, I have   jute.maxbuffer=1073741824
But in zk logs during start up, I've got
2024-07-09 14:12:58,105 [myid:] - INFO  [QuorumPeermyid=1(secure=disabled):o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer@1633] - The max bytes for all large requests are set to 104857600
And eventually, I've got IO len error:
zookeeper-0 java.io.IOException: Len error. A message from /10.42.18.0:45980 with advertised length of 973078528 is either a malformed message or too large to process (length is greater than jute.maxbuffer=1048575)
my question is why the jute.maxbuffer value in zookeeper.properties is not taken

If the value of jute.maxbuffer is too high, ZK seems to ignore it
See this link
https://user.zookeeper.apache.narkive.com/bveQQuI1/configuring-jute-maxbuffer-on-zookeeper-nodes

thanks. we identified the root cause of this issue.
The zk cluster was deployed in k8s, although we changed the mapping court, the zk itself is still using 2181 default port.  so some un-expected traffic was received, what we did was to to change networkpolicy.allowExternal to false.
